# How does Spring pick the implementation of an @Autowired List

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I use the following code in a Spring application to have multiple beans that implement the same interface injected into a list:

```
@Autowired
List<SomeType> mylist;
```

i can see via reflection that `mylist` is of type `java.util.ArrayList`.

How does Spring pick exactly this implementation of the `java.util.List` interface and how can this behaviour be changed ?

Comment: I don't think that spring provides a hook for the list implementation, because of the injection features (example ordered elements).  I would with the easy way-> convert ArrayList to what you need.

Comment: I think it's about how you populate `List<SomeType>`, if you return an `ArrayList<SomeType> from the `@Bean` method, then it's going to be an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

By bean name.

For example, let's say you are configuring two beans of the same type:

```
@Bean
public List<SomeType> listA(){
    // Init and return listA here
}

@Bean
public List<SomeType> listB(){
    // Init and return listB here
}
```

and when you use `@Autowired` as this:

```
@Autowired(value = "listA") List<SomeType> listA;
```

you'll see that it will be autowired to `listA` whereas the following will be autowired to `listB`:

```
@Autowired(value = "listB") List<SomeType> listB;
```

Comment: I don't think that is the question OP is asking. He wants to know why Spring chooses `ArrayList` as the implementation for the `List` interface.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry totally misunderstood.